# Setting an example answer in a text input field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to set a default value in a text input field which gives the user an example of what to enter. This should be greyed-out and should disappear as soon as they start typing. I've tried setting an `initial` value but this isn't automatically replaced when the user starts to type and is formatted the same as the user-entered answer.

```
form = VerbTestForm(initial={'answer': tip.tip})
```

What do I need to pass to my form to get the behaviour I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting an **initial value** but you're looking for a **placeholder**.

You should try something like this:

```
class VerbTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Your code ...
    class Meta:
        # Your code ...

        widgets = {
            'answer': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': tip.tip}),
        }
```

or you can add the placeholder after defining the form like:

```
form = VerbTestForm()
form.fields['answer'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = tip.tip
```

The official documentation is quite well explained, you should check:

- [Django Form Widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/)

Comment: I was missing the name "placeholder"

Answer (score 1):

Set the widget's `placeholder` attribute:

```
form = VerbTestForm()
form.fields['answer'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = tip.tip
```

Answer (score 1):

A widget placeholder is your answer:

```
 class VerbTestForm(forms.Form):
     answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': tip.tip}))
```

you can quickly test the generated HTML by calling the as_p or as_table methods

```
>>> f = VerbTestForm(auto_id=False)
>>> f.as_table()
```